# How to solve Django 'setup.py' not found in Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: python, linux, django

I'm trying to install Django to Linux Mint 18.1 with terminal. I am getting the same problem. My python version is 3.5.2

When i try to command

```
$ -H  pip install -e django/
```

I get this

```
Directory 'django/' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
##### this installs globally    
sudo pip install django
```

Also , the right way to do this is not install your packages globally. 
Create a virtualenv in your projects directory.

```
pip install virtualenv #Install python virtualenv
virtualenv my_project #setup a virtualenv environment
cd my_project #go to virtualenv
source bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install django ## Install django
django-admin.py startproject my_project ## Start django project my_project
```